# Flask - reloading app if external data (e.g. database) is updated

Tags: python, sql, flask

I developed a python Flask app that is connected to a local database and I make the SQL query at the loading of the Flask app so I can store the result in memory.

But the database is updated several times a day (not at specific hours) and I would like to reload the app as soon as the DB is updated.

I found the "extra_files" app.run argument way, but it does not fit my request.

Comment: Is there any reason you cannot simply make live SQL queries of the db when the data is needed?  While I'm sure it's possible to create a simple script which reloads the Flask app when the db is updated, it seems a highly unusual requirement.

Comment: The SQL query requires couples of minutes so it cannot be live.